# How to check if returned actor proxy instance is valid

Tags: c#, azure, azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-actor

Let's assume the following code snippet as the example:

```
        ICustomActor puller = ActorProxy.Create<ICustomActor>(ActorId.CreateRandom(),
            new Uri("some_actor_URI"));
```

The ActorProxy.Create works in a way that even if *some_actor_URI* is incorrect, there is no exception thrown or null returned. The result is always some proxy object. When invoking an actor's method on that proxy the replica crashes without exception.

The problem is that there is no obvious way to check if the resolved proxy is correct.

How can I check if the resolved actor proxy instance leads to the existing Service Fabric actor instance?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you passing the uri?

Comment: Anyway, just tried it but it throws an error indicating the url is incorrect as soon as I try to use the proxy by making calls.

Comment: I just began exploring that technology and I didn't know about other approaches. Which version of Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Actors.Client you are using?

Comment: 3.2.162. Can you post the whole method including the actual call to the actor?

Comment: The call looks exactly like the one included as the example. And I can successfully invoke methods via remoting. My only concern is how to add some checking to make code more fault tolerant.

Comment: But your first comment suggests that there different way of creating actor proxy. Is there?